# screen shots taken in ubuntu are not opening in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, screenshot

I have dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 13.04. Screen shots taken in Ubuntu with printscreen do not work inside windows 8. I can't even open them with paint,windows photo viewer, PHOTOS, photoshop or with any other software.

EDIT:
problem solved after renaming the screen shots in ubuntu to something smaller like 1.png etc

Possible reasons of error are:

- By default, screen capture in ubuntu give long name to screen shots e.g. "Screenshot at 2013-05-20 00:46:45"
- Long names are not supported in windows 8 so windows 8 can't open png files with that type of names

Comment: Can you upload one? Perhaps upload one from within Ubuntu (having tested it) and the same file from within Windows. It sounds like they're becoming corrupted at some point. If you stick two copies online we can objectively compare the data.

Comment: Can you open them in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I can open them in ubuntu

Comment: When you opened the images in Windows 8 did they had the correct file extension?. Windows is very special about this, if you tell it an image has .iso as its extension it will try to burn a disc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you are facing probably isn't the lengh of the name, but the presence of colon `:` which isn't accepted by the filesystem most Windows use, i. e., NTFS.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS